# Create article as menu item

Tags: php, joomla

I am fairly new to using Joomla (3.3) and I followed the instructions on a post here to create an article programmatically using this code:

```
<?php
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php')) {
   include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php';
}
if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
   define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
   require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php';
}

define('JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR', JPATH_BASE . DS . 'administrator' . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_content');
require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/framework.php';


require_once JPATH_BASE. "/administrator/components/com_content/models/article.php";


$app = JFactory::getApplication('site', array('session' => false));

$new_article = new ContentModelArticle();

$data = array(
    'catid' => '17',
    'title' => 'Title',
    'introtext' => '<h4><strong>Intro Text Here</strong></h4>',
    'fulltext' => '<p>This is the full text paragraph </p>'
    'state' => 1,
);
$new_article->save($data);
```

I'd like to be able to create the article as a menu item but I'm not even sure where to even start. Any help appreciated.

Regards

Jim

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making it a bit more complicated than it needs to be. In fact it's pretty simple. In your administrator panel, go to you menu.

Menus > Main Menu (or which menu you want) > Click on 'Add new' > Menu Item Type (click) > Click 'Articles' to expand the section > Single Article

When you do that you will have an option open up where you can select the article you want to be on that menu item.